# Can't disable ECC checking on Tricore TC39XX

Tags: flash, memory, microcontroller, infineon

**First question** : How can I disable ECC safey error in infineon TRICORE TC39XX

I used to disable it in TC27 using this cocde

```
 /* Deactivate ECC safety errors */
Mcal_ResetENDINIT();
FLASH0_ECCRP0.B.ECCORDIS |= IFX_FLASH_ECCRP_ECCORDIS_MSK;
FLASH0_ECCRP1.B.ECCORDIS |= IFX_FLASH_ECCRP_ECCORDIS_MSK;
Mcal_SetENDINIT();
```

now I'm tying to disable it on TC39XX with this code `DMU_HF_ECCC.B.ECCCORDIS = 0x01`; but it's not working

Should I set `PECENCDIS` and `DECENCDIS` flags ?

**Second question** when enabling ECC, why can't I read the flash memory ? I thought it will just not use ECC checking ?